# Why I getting (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).reduce is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I running Angular 11 and I have the following expression with checks to avoid calling reduce on a undefined value:

```
  (this.budgetConfiguration?.consumption ?? []).reduce((accumulatorValue, currentValue) => (accumulatorValue || 0) + (currentValue || 0) , 0);
```

which throws the following error:

> core.js:5980 ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate
> value)(intermediate value).reduce is not a function

But if I execute that expression just as it is(you can try, just copy and paste) in chrome console returns a 0 value that is what I expect from my piece of code.

It's not a complex sentence, I just using elvis operator to change undefined for an empty array when is required.

So, what i'm doing wrong?
Why Typescript doesn't like this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the enclosing code surrounding this?

Comment: Is a class method. After a bit of testing I can see I need a more exhaustive value control, given I taking care of undefined values but it happens when consumption is  a simple value like 55(it's not undefined neither an array). It was my fault. Thanks for your time anyway ;)